# CRM 2011 - Mapping

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Today I was try use mapping on Invoice Form Entity. 
First time I was surprised because mapping is not working? 
But after refresh page I seen - mapping is worked.

**So my question is:** 
How I can force work mapping without refresh?

**Update**

[image]

This image with my steps.It is strange because as I know mapping work without refresh.
Or refresh this is important step?

Comment: can you explain better your problem? add one or more screenshot if necessary

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on how you are mapping. Is it a JavaScript request which is populating the field? If so, then the value should appear immediately. The example you show suggests the record is being updated in the background and then the record retrieval is returning the value when you refresh.

Comment: No, I am using CRM relationship mapping.